# How to deal with background images with 100% width and height in mobile and tab screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive

I have few pages where I have included a background image with width 100% and height 100% in every page. That means whenever a page is loaded you'll see an image with 100% screen's size. Everything is perfect when I see these pages in my laptop. I'm facing problems when I view them in mobile screens.

I just want to know how do everyone deal in these situations. I mean how to make changes to my main div with width and height 100% in responsive screens?

The image is getting stretched if I set the background size to 100%.

Some part of the image is cut if I set the background size to contain.

I want the image's clarity should be perfect. Should I make the width of the main div to auto? Or else should I change the image in responsive screens?

Is there anyway to make this div look better in small screens?

I just want my main div to be apt in **Responsive screens.**

It shouldn't look line there is a defect in the image or in my code.

Here's my code of the main div :

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/8/8c/Wolverine_Vol_3_73_Variant_Frame_Textless.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090925123509');
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">

</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest `background-size` to be used from any of `cover/contain/100% 100%`.

Comment: @HardikVaghani as I mentioned that is not looking good when I use them in responsive screens, If the background image is viewed in small screens it should be perfect it shouldn't stretch and it shouldn't even cut some part of the image

Comment: try looking into srcset attribute. It lets the browser figure out which image is the best for the particular screen size. More info: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Comment: Sure, I'll look into it, Hope it helps :)

Comment: Did u try adding bootstrap class `img-responsive`

Comment: @LiniSusanV I want the image to be as a background image So I did not use img-responsive class on it

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to make image responsive. Please `Google` out the approach that best suits your requirement. The solution which you will find helpful depends on the image that you are using. It depends on the size and quality of image.

I find the following links helpful.

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

For Responsive Image

```
 .class_name{
  max-width: 100%, 
  height: auto,
  display:block
}
```

And Full Screen Responsive Image use individual class like

```
.class_name{
        background-image: url(image path) ;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat:  no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size:  cover;
        background-color: #999;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  max-width: 2000px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

.main-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/8/8c/Wolverine_Vol_3_73_Variant_Frame_Textless.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090925123509');
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">

</div>
```

this should make it responsive. I don't know what you want the DIV to be like, so I left that alone.